# how to change the accessibility of Google Drive file on insert the file using Javascript Google Picker API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-oauth, google-picker

i try to using Google Drive Picker API to upload new images or insert images to my CMS.

it's working. I can get image URL. But the problerm is: accessibility  of the file that uploaded at Google Drive is a private by default (only me as a Owner can view it by Login Google Account). But this images is viewable to anyone on browser when i manually change accessibility setting of file to **Public or Anyone with link** from Google Drive site.

My point here: how to change the accessibility of Google Drive file on insert the file using Google Picker javascript API (change/set accessbility to Public or anyone with link). Below is my current code.

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        /**
         * Initialise a Google Driver file picker
         */
        var FilePicker = window.FilePicker = function(options) {
            // Config
            this.apiKey = options.apiKey;
            this.clientId = options.clientId;

            // Elements
            this.buttonEl = options.buttonEl;

            // Events
            this.onSelect = options.onSelect;

            this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));

            // Disable the button until the API loads, as it won&#39;t work properly until then.
            this.buttonEl.disabled = true;

            // Load the drive API
            gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', this._driveApiLoaded.bind(this));
            google.load('picker', '1', {
                callback: this._pickerApiLoaded.bind(this)
            });
        }


        FilePicker.prototype = {
            /**
             * Open the file picker.
             */
            open: function() {
                // Check if the user has already authenticated
                var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
                if (token) {
                    this._showPicker();
                } else {
                    // The user has not yet authenticated with Google
                    // We need to do the authentication before displaying the Drive picker.
                    this._doAuth(false, function() {
                        this._showPicker();
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            },

            /**
             * Show the file picker once authentication has been done.
             * @private
             */
            _showPicker: function() {
                var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
                var view = new google.picker.DocsView();
                var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView();
                var viewss = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
                viewss.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg');
                view.setIncludeFolders(true);
                this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES)
                    .addView(viewss)
                    .addView(uploadView)
                    .setAppId(this.clientId)
                    .setDeveloperKey(this.apiKey)
                    .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
                    .setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this))
                    .build()
                    .setVisible(true);
            },

            /**
             * Called when a file has been selected in the Google Drive file picker.
             * @private
             */
            _pickerCallback: function(data) {
                if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                    var fruits, fLen, i;

                    fruits = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
                    fLen = fruits.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

                        var file = fruits[i];
                        var id = file[google.picker.Document.ID];
                        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                            fileId: id
                        });

                        request.execute(this._fileGetCallback.bind(this));
                    }
                }
            },
            /**
             * Called when file details have been retrieved from Google Drive.
             * @private
             */
            _fileGetCallback: function(file) {
                if (this.onSelect) {
                    this.onSelect(file);
                }
            },

            /**
             * Called when the Google Drive file picker API has finished loading.
             * @private
             */
            _pickerApiLoaded: function() {
                this.buttonEl.disabled = false;
            },

            /**
             * Called when the Google Drive API has finished loading.
             * @private
             */
            _driveApiLoaded: function() {
                this._doAuth(true);
            },

            /**
             * Authenticate with Google Drive via the Google JavaScript API.
             * @private
             */
            _doAuth: function(immediate, callback) {
                gapi.auth.authorize({
                    client_id: this.clientId,
                    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                    immediate: immediate
                }, callback);
            }

        };
    }());
    //]]>
</script>
<script>
        function initPicker() {

            var picker = new FilePicker({
                apiKey: 'HAHAblaBlaWTFashjahsgtP6BwWPf3Liukk',
                clientId: '978946248407-WTFhahaBlaBla4q0f5c.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick_image'),
                onSelect: function(file) {                  
console.log(JSON.stringify(file)); 
console.log(file); 
console.log(file.title);
console.log(file.webContentLink);
$('#post-editor').append('<a  href="'+file.webContentLink+'" class="center_img"><img src="'+file.webContentLink+'"/></a>');     
                }
            });
        }
</script>

<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=HAHAblaBlaWTFashjahsgtP6BwWPf3Liukk'></script>

<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker'></script>

<button id='pick_image'>CLICK HERE INSERT OR UPLOAD IMAGE</button>
<!-- Image HTML will append to #post-editor below -->

<div id='post-editor' contenteditable='true' style='width:100%; height:200px'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you need to set a [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) to the file. What you need to set is the `role` and the `type`.

Here is the sample code from the documentation.

```
function insertPermission(fileId, value, type, role) {
var body = {
'value': value,
'type': type,
'role': role
};
var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
'fileId': fileId,
'resource': body
});
request.execute(function(resp) { });
}
```

For more information, check these related SO questions:

- [How to make the file shareable using google drive api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198386/how-to-make-the-file-shareable-using-google-drive-api/36228784)
- [Google drive Public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208819/google-drive-public)

Comment: How to implement it with my current code. Update permission **on insert**